# How to disable visualization of gridlines in holoviews heatmap

Tags: python, bokeh, heatmap, holoviews

I am using `hv.HeatMap` to plot a connectiviy matrix. I would like to disable the viszualization of the gridlines. At first I thought this should be possible be disabling `show_grid` but this does not have any effect on  the gridlines.

For example, how would one disable the visulization in the [last example from the documentation](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HeatMap.html)?

```
heatmap = hv.HeatMap((np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 100), 
                      np.random.randn(100), np.random.randn(100)), vdims=['z', 'z2']).sort().aggregate(function=np.mean)

heatmap.opts(opts.HeatMap(tools=['hover'], colorbar=True, width=325, toolbar='above', clim=(-2, 2)))
```

which produces:

[image]´

When you have a close look (or better zoom in, using the interactive plot on the documentation page), you can see, that all 'boxes' are surrounded with a white border. I would like to disable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate or deactivate a grid you can add `show_grid=True` or `show_grid=False` to `opts.HeatMap(...)`.

**But** in your example there is no grid activated, so you can't deactivate the grid lines. The white lines you can see are coming through the background color (which is defined by default as white).

You could change the background adding `bgcolor ='#ABABAB'` to `opts.HeatMap(...)`, which makes a figure like

[image: Background changed].

But sometimes you have to apply the changes you want to make directly in the bokeh figure object because not all the possibilities are added to `holoviews` keyword arguments. If you have to do this, you can follow this [introduction](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html#working-with-bokeh-directly).

Extend your example with the following to add an alpha value to the background as an example:

```python
from bokeh.io import (
    show,
    export_png,
    export_svgs,
    output_file,
    save,
)

# get bokeh object
fig = hv.render(heatmap)
# make some changes
fig.background_fill_alpha = 0.5
# show figure in notebook
show(fig)
```

If you have an bokeh figure object and want to save the figure as `png`, `html` or `svg` you can`t use` holoviews` anymore, because there is no way to transform it back (as far as I know).

Then you have to use the the functions available from `bokeh.io` to save them.

You can use:

```python
# png
export_png(fig, filename = 'heatmap.png')

# svg
fig.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(fig, filename = 'heatmap.svg')

# html
output_file('heatmap.html', mode='inline')
save(fig, filename = 'heatmap.html', title = 'heatmap', resources=None)
```

All thise and more is explained in the [`bokeh.io` documentation](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html)

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for making that clear! So it's not possible to do this using `.otps`  or something like this? I need to save the resulting figure on the hard drive, how would I achieve this after running `fig = hv.render(heatmap)`?

Comment: You can save this figure using the save-icon to get a `png`. Other options are descriped [here](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html#exporting-static-files). The easiest is `hv.save(heatmap, 'heatmap.png')` where you can exchange the file-suffix (`png` and `html` are supported, maybe also `svg`).

Comment: But saving the heatmap using `hv.save(heatmap,'heatmap.png'`) would save it without your additional steps? Wouldn't I need something like `hv.save(fig,'heatmap.png')`? However, when I try this it gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'traverse'`

Comment: If you want to save it with the changes, you have to use bokehs implementation of [`save`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=save#bokeh.io.save), [`export_png` or `export_svg`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=save#bokeh-io-export).

Comment: `bokeh.io.save(fig,'./heatmap.html')` gives me this error: `...\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io\saving.py:126: UserWarning: save() called but no resources were supplied and output_file(...) was never called, defaulting to resources.CDN
  warn("save() called but no resources were supplied and output_file(...) was never called, defaulting to resources.CDN")`

Comment: @JohannesWiesner Please check my edit. I think in your case you don't have to use the workaround with `bokeh`. But I also show how to save a figure using `bokeh`.